# Open Source dictionary libraries

Tags: java, open-source, dictionary

I am looking for a free to use dictionary in as many spoken languages (english, french, german, ...) as possible.

basically i will need to check if a string exists in a dictionary.

i was thinking about the dictionaries used in firefox or openoffice, since they should be open-source, right? where can i find and download them?

also ideally exists a java library to access the data in the dictionary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free or open source multilingual dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026776/free-or-open-source-multilingual-dictionary)

Comment: I wouldn's consider this question a possible duplicate since it's wearing the java tag.

Answer (score 9):

Unpack [Debian's freedict packages](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=freedict&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all).

Answer (score 3):

There is a free dictionary available **WordNet**

Please check this site  http://wordnet.princeton.edu/

To connect dictionary from java there are many api available. Some of them are.

http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwordnet/

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu Linux distribution comes with a plain English dictionary (words only). They are stored in

```
/usr/local/share/dict
```

I thought. Now I see *palacsint* his answer popping up. I think it are the same dictionaries.