# In java, is there a way to generate a valid dictionary word of certain length randomly?

Tags: java

I need to generate a valid dictionary word of certain length but in a random fashion. Is there an api or code snippet that does this? I tried googling it but couldn't find anything for this.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660839/open-source-dictionary-libraries

Comment: You should work on your googling. If you couldn't find anything, then there's likely a lot of other resources that you can't find just because you don't know how to use Google efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download this *[.csv](http://www.filedrake.com/OHh4CF)* file which has around 200 thousand *English* words.
You can then parse the `.csv` file, add the entries to an `ArrayList`. Then create a function that randomly generates a number between the available indices of the `ArrayList` and then use it to get an entry at that *random index*. Or, you can think of something alike yourself.

Comment: Yeah I had this idea but I was looking for some Java class or some ext library that does it. But thank you so much anyway, will go with this only if nothing else comes up.

Comment: Do give me an up-vote if my answer was helpful to you.

Comment: Hey Lance, i did up-vote your answer but i think due to my less reputation points, it's not showing. I appreciate your time.